# What is this C# construct doing and why? MyClass<TMyClass> : MyClass where

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I came across the following code, all in a single file/class.  I'm leaving out the details, its the construct I'm interested in.  Why are there two different declarations for the same class and how are they different?  What's the purpose of the syntax for the second declaration?

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    ...
}

public abstract class MyClass<TMyClass> : MyClass
    where TMyClass: MyClass<TMyClass>
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public abstract class MyClass<TMyClass> : MyClass
    where TMyClass: MyClass<TMyClass>
{
    ...
}
```

is a class that inherits from `MyClass`, and it takes a generic type, which has to inherit from `MyClass<TMyClass>`

---

Here's a simpler example of the same thing for you

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyClass<Myclass> other = new MyClass<Myclass>(new Myclass());
        List<int> intlist = new List<int>();
    }

    public class Myclass
    {
        public Myclass()
        {
        }
        public int i { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyClass<T> where T : Myclass
    {
        T value;
        public MyClass(T val)
        {
            value = val;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So this second class has the same name but because it has a generic Type Parameter, its a different class?  How would I descend from that?

Comment: @SteveWash and yes, the are different classes

Comment: -1: The "simple" example is **very** different from what the original code does. Labeling it "the same thing" is both wrong and misleading.

Comment: Thanks to everyone's post's. Lots of good info here for me to pick through and do some research on.

Comment: @Jon  no, it's not functionally equivalent, but it does use the exact same operators that the OP's example does.

Answer (score 3):

`MyClass` - A abstract class named MyClass.

`MyClass<TMyClass> : MyClass` - A abstract generic class named `MyClass<>` but with a generic type named `TMyClass`.

If you rename the types, it will be easier to see:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    ...
}

public abstract class MyClass<T> : MyBaseClass
    where T: MyClass<T>
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Types with different generic arity (i.e. number of generic type parameters, which can be zero or more) are considered as completely unrelated by the language and can have the same name.

This means that you can have classes `Foo`, `Foo<T>` and `Foo<T,U>` at the same time; the syntax will allow the compiler to determine which you are referring to. You can see this happen in the base framework which includes [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx), [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) etc.

The "recursive" construct `class C<T> where T: C<T>` (the inheritance from a non-generic `C` does not change anything so I removed it) is the C# on what is called the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) (CRTP) in C++. Eric Lippert [has covered this subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx) very well in a blog post, where the conclusion is that one should think more than twice before implementing this -- there are problems it can solve, but the solution also has a price.

Answer (score 0):

It's a classic idiom, the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern, done in C#.

It means the template can only be used thusly:

```
class Foo : MyClass<Foo>
{
}
```

In this construction, `Foo` inherits `MyClass<Foo>` which inherits `MyClass`.

This has a few advantages, but I've forgotten which.

Answer (score -1):

```
 public abstract class MyClass<TMyClass> : MyClass
       where TMyClass: MyClass<TMyClass>
 {
        ...
 }
```

First thing to point out is that this is an abstract class that is inheriting from another abstract class. In other words, this is a class that cannot be instantiated (without another class inheriting from it), but is using inheritence to derive the functionality from another abstract class (which is fine).

The second thing to point out, is that this is a Template class (or generic class as they call it in C#) which accepts type in it's . I would reduce that to T as a convention so that T is always a template, though it is completely up to you what you call things.

Lastly there is a constraint on this which is kind of strange. It says that, no matter what, the compiler will not allow any class type to be passed in as a template type, unless it inherits from (somewhere along the inheritance chain)

```
 MyClass<TMyClass>
```

This is shown in the following line

```
 where TMyClass: MyClass<TMyClass>
```

basically this prevents anyone from passing in an object that does not follow this rule.

What is a bit odd is that the constraints tells the implementer that it cannot be a template unless the type passed by template is in fact a type of itself. You as the designer of this class (or implementer) has to decide if this is a wise design, though this in itself looks a bit strange.